# Finding MAX after 2 JOINs between 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 tables employees, salaries and dept_emps in below given format:

Employees:

```
emp_no     first_name
---------------------
01         ABC
02         XYZ
03         MNO
04         PQR
```

Salaries:

```
emp_no     salary
-------------------
01          10000
02          20000
03          15000
04         100000
```

dept_emp:

```
emp_no     dept_no
------------------
01         d01
02         d02
03         d01
04         d02
```

Required output:

dept_no and emp_id of employee with highest salary in that department

```
dept_no    emp_id
------------------
d01        03
d02        04
```

I tried using filtering with a subquery, but it got stuck like a infinite loop without output:

```
SELECT first_name, dept_no
FROM employees e 
JOIN salaries s USING (emp_no)
JOIN dept_emp de USING (emp_no)
WHERE s.salary = (SELECT MAX(salary)
                  FROM dept_emp de2
                  JOIN salaries USING (emp_no)
                  WHERE de2.dept_no = de.dept_no);
```

What is the efficient query for this and why is my query not working?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: There is no "infinite loop" in SQL. What happens when you try and run the query against a small dataset?

Comment: No the data set has hundreds of thousands rows, but I waited for few minutes

Comment: Strawberry, all features of tables are clearly available in the question, what more do you want me to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra nested query with aggregation that calculates maximum salaries per each department such as

```
SELECT ss.dept_no, s.emp_no as emp_id
  FROM salaries s
  JOIN
   (
    SELECT d.dept_no, MAX(s.salary) AS max_salary
      FROM salaries s 
      JOIN dept_emp d USING (emp_no)
     GROUP BY d.dept_no 
   ) ss
    ON s.salary = ss.max_salary
```

P.S: `employees` table is not needed

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02f6684a053a9c0055178611c058de70)</kbd>

If your DB's version is 8, then use an analytic function such as `DENSE_RANK()` within a subquery :

```
SELECT dept_no, emp_no AS emp_id
  FROM
  (
    SELECT d.dept_no, s.emp_no, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY d.dept_no ORDER BY s.salary DESC) AS dr
      FROM salaries s 
      JOIN dept_emp d 
        ON d.emp_no = s.emp_no
  ) sd     
 WHERE dr = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3bf4c91f39bc7404a45c52eab34239a1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you can just use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*,
       (select e.first_name
        from dept_emp de join
             employees e
             using (emp_no) join
             salaries s
             using (emp_no)
        where de.dept_no = d.dept_no
        order by s.salary desc
        limit 1
       ) as first_name
from departments d;
```

This assumes that you have a table with the departments, which seems reasonable.